# Predefined domain name in TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart, textformfield

I am designing SignIn form for my app. There I need to design a custom TextFormField. In that I have to add a fix domain name at end of TextFormField. But I am not getting the way to do this.
For reference I am sharing design.

[image]

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60204200/13625305), might help.

Comment: @dev-aentgs its only related to suffix/Prefix icons

Comment: There is `suffixText:` property. Another way would be to have `TextField` and `Text` in a `Column`.

Comment: TextFormField(                
                onChanged: (value) {
                  print(value);
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Team doamin",
                  suffix: Text('.xyz.com'),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ))

Comment: suffix Text display only when your have initial value or have focus.